# What is the best way to create an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, php, loops

I have been using a while loop for this but recently got into debate with a friend over what form of iteration is the best way to establish an infinite loop in PHP?

Which is the best type of iteration to infinitely loop?

Comment: Why would you want to loop infinitely?

Comment: Breaking your loops is so 2008. I usually opt for the classic `while(1)` when I want to bring my machine to its knees and make it say *uncle*.

Comment: I like the guts in this question.

Comment: The while loop does not increment a counter variable making it the most suitable.

Comment: Such a pointless question, yet I can't stop reading it over and over...

Comment: The responses to this question are enormously entertaining, but to be fair to crm, there are actually valid reasons to put an infinite loop in php. When combined with a sleep function, this can be useful (especially for socket programming). Also, as a matter of form you should use `while($var===true)` to make it easier to add breakout conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(true)
{
     // ...
}
```

Because, in this case the condition evaluation will be minimal.

BTW, do you really have to loop infinitely? You know what you are doing right? I hope! :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's personal preference.  I personally like `while(1){}`, as it's easier for me to spot than `for(;;){}`.